# Is it possible - use redisearch for caseless search?

Tags: redis, full-text-search, redisearch

So, using redisearch-py, search by 'test' and 'TEST' gives for me different results. How i can make a query for caseless full text search?

Comment: Can you give a full example? RediSearch should be case insensitive